# Server side admin clients in Firebase? For example for a banking app

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-hosting

Let's say you want to use firebase to allow people to play a betting game and they would get points.

The questions are:

1. if there is no server side code then who decides the winner of the bet?
2. who would be the authority that would give points to the users?

If an individual user has write access to their own points, they could update it (which is not what we want)

The solution that we thought about is a admin node firebase client running on a server.  It would listen and make decisions and write to the points location for each user.  Users would only have read access.

But this means that there would have to be scalable server or servers.  This seems to be a single point of failure.  Plus what if you have 100's of admin firebase clients running, that could be a synchronization issue.

What is the best practice for this type of problem?

I suspect all games must have this issue? no?

Comment: You're looking for Firebase Queue. See this [blog post](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-05-15-introducing-firebase-queue.html) announcing it and the [Github repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue) hosting it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Wow! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use App Engine for backend processing, which is Google's "serverless" solution. Checkout this solution: [Using Firebase for Real-time Events on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-firebase-real-time-events-app-engine). It think it solves your questions.